# Run a webpage from Shell

Tags: php, shell, cron

I have created a php file I want to run every day at 8am on my linux webserver.  The page is accessible online, but I want to schedule a cronjob to basically mimic a request to the page every day at 8am.  Is this possible? if so, how?

Comment: What do you want to happen specifically?  What kind of request?

Comment: I've written a small app in JS and PHP that scrapes a website and then the JS uses an API to write the results to another webapp.  For some reason, I can't get the thing working at all though.  Seems to run it fine, but doesn't execute.

Comment: you will need to convert the whole thing to PHP, because JS wont run through cron/wget

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just run a `wget` command to make a request to the page, using a cronjob.

Comment: the JS on the page (which McB mentions in the comment) wont run, will it ?

Comment: @Phoenix I hadn't noticed that comment.  Could McB get away with launching an instance of an actual browser with the URL?

Answer (score 0):

As suggested here you should use a cron job to send this request to your PHP script @ 8AM every day. From the cron job you have many options to send this request (use only one of these):

1. Use wget to simulate a request to your web server
2. Use curl to simulate a request to your web server
3. Use PHP CLI /usr/bin/php -q  (most of the $_SERVER variables will defer in this case)